# Android GoogleAPIClient, Not able to get location for first time in app launch

Tags: android, location, google-api-client

I want to make an activity where I will take some action on location change. SO there are two things needed to be taken care, if GPS is not on, then setting intent for GPS is launched. And if location permission is not given then Location Request Dialog opens. It works well in all cases but when GPS is on and I am opening for first time then it doesn't work.

**Code**

```
package in.co.palup.android;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * Home activity
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION = 1;

    /**
     * Http connection timeout
     */
    private final int TIME_OUT = 60 * 1000;

    /**
     * Tag for logger.
     */
    private final String TAG = "Home";

    /**
     * Dialog to show when loading is going in background
     */
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    /**
     * Google API client.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;

    /**
     * Location request.
     */
    private LocationRequest locationRequest;

    /**
     * The location manager
     */
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_palup_home);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Create new event");
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EventCreation.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }

        locationManager =
                (android.location.LocationManager) this.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            this.startActivity(intent);
        }

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE_LOCATION);
        }

    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        locationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        locationRequest.setInterval(10000);
        locationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
        locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates() {
        if (googleApiClient == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "client is null");
        }
        if (locationRequest == null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "location request is null");
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                googleApiClient, locationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.palup_home, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        googleApiClient.connect();
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        googleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && locationManager.isProviderEnabled(android.location.LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            createLocationRequest();
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("onLocationChanged", location.toString());

        // TODO: take action on location
    }
}
```

Comment: whats that java script link in your Q??

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kuldeepiitg/bc7d7b9f6b9aa9e859ca

Comment: It is link to code in github. Click Run code snippet.

Comment: no need for that, you can add the code in the Q. its easier